# a4j:commandLink action and onclick asynchronous calls with a pop up panel

Tags: jsf, asynchronous, synchronous, ajax4jsf, commandlink

Im having a issue with this code, I'm trying to display a popupPanel to performe an action before going to another facelet, the issue is the popup shows for just a moment before the new facelet is render, I think it has something to do with asynchronous calls, but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks

```
                <h:outputText value="Do you want to save your changes?"/>
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <a4j:region id="panel-region">
                        <h:commandButton action="#{saveReminderBackingBean.saveBundle}" value=" Yes " onclick="#{rich:component('savePopupPanel')}.hide();bm.showLoading()" styleClass="pnx-btn pnx-btn-secondary " style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px"/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <h:commandButton action="#{saveReminderBackingBean.clearFlags}" value="No" onclick="#{rich:component('savePopupPanel')}.hide();bm.showLoading()" styleClass="pnx-btn pnx-btn-secondary " style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px"/>

                </a4j:region>
                <br/>
                </div>
            </rich:popupPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<h:commandButton/>` will trigger a full JSF POST request, so the popup that was created and shown will be automatically closed as the whole page is being rendered at the end of the request.

You should replace the command button with an `<a4j:commandButton/>`

```
    <a4j:commandButton action="#{saveReminderBackingBean.saveBundle}" value=" Yes " onclick="#{rich:component('savePopupPanel')}.hide();bm.showLoading()" styleClass="pnx-btn pnx-btn-secondary " style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a4j:commandButton action="#{saveReminderBackingBean.clearFlags}" value="No" onclick="#{rich:component('savePopupPanel')}.hide();bm.showLoading()" styleClass="pnx-btn pnx-btn-secondary " style="padding-left:8px;padding-right:8px"/>
```

The `<a4j:commandButton/>` triggers a partial request, rather than a full request. As a result, the page isn't reloaded and your popup will stay open